# ionic virtualscroll shows only the first 5 items

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm not sure if it's a bug within `Ionic`, or I'm doing something wrong. I'm trying to use `virtualscroll` with `ion-img` to generate an array of 100 image links.

## Code

```
posts: Array<any> = [];
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, private http: Http) {
    for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++)
      this.posts.push('https://unsplash.it/200/150?image=' + i);
  }
```

## HTML

```
<ion-content>

  <ion-list [virtualScroll]="posts" approxItemHeight="150px" bufferRatio="1">

    <ion-item *virtualItem="let post;">
      <ion-card>
        <div style="width:100%;height:150px">
          <ion-img width="100%" height="150px" cache="true" [src]="post"></ion-img>
        </div>
        <ion-card-content>
          <ion-card-title>
            Nine Inch Nails Live
          </ion-card-title>
          <p>
            The most popular industrial group ever, and largely responsible for bringing the music to a mass audience.
          </p>
        </ion-card-content>
      </ion-card>
    </ion-item>

  </ion-list>

</ion-content>
```

It's only showing/rendering the first 5 posts. Is there something missing, or am I doing it wrong?

EDITED :  [a live demo can be found here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-4vdp9u)

Comment: Could you make a demo ?

Comment: @Vega where can I add an online demo?

Comment: Fork from here :) https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-ar9gdf

Comment: @Vega done!....

Comment: There is definitely  a bug, specially on ion-img. I think the issue is still not resolved, there are so many issue reports, last one (I think) : github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/11326. There are some workaround suggested, maybe that would help? But <img> works